# Whats wrong with this VB code?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function nameTonumber(name As String)

    Dim number As Integer
    number = 0

    If (name = "Aa") Then

        number = 1

    ElseIf (name = "Bb") Then

        number = 2

    ElseIf (name = "Cc") Then

        number = 3

    Else

        number = 0

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Is this VB.NET or VB6? And the next time you ask a question, **be specific**. You ask what’s wrong? Well, why do you want to know? What is not working?

Comment: Ok after End if I added; return number; still doesn't work?

Comment: To return a value from a function, use `nameToNumber=number` or `return number` (which form depends on which version of VB you're using) once you have worked out what 'number' should be.

Comment: @user1079898 Your comment suffers from the same problems I outlined in my first comment. You once again did not provide *nearly* enough information.

Comment: @user1079898, are you using VB6 or VB.NET? Is it a web application or a desktop application? What does the function return when you add: return number? (as per your comment) does it return 0?

Comment: Its VB6. I was doing this to enter it as a function in excel on my desktop. First day with VB. Just wanted to get the basics right. The return number command returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first line to: Function nameTonumber(name As String) As Integer

Above End Function add:

nameTonumber=number 'If you are using VB6.

return number 'If you are using VB.NET

Answer (score 2):

1. The parentheses around the `If` conditionals are redundant.
2. The `Else` is redundant – `number` is already zero.
3. You do not return any value.
4. You did not specify a return type.
5. You can use `Select Case` to make multiple tests of this form marginally more readable.

And a lot more if this is VB.NET code.

On a stylistic note, your code takes up too much space: remove the unnecessary empty lines, they do not serve to make the code more readable – on the contrary.

Comment: You forgot "0. The fact that it is VB" :P